# Reactivate "classic" bootscreen

Tags: boot

How can I reactivate the old bootscreen on startup?

Currently, on power on, my laptop shows a screen similar to the following: 
[image]

Can I get the "classic" screen back that looks like this:
[image]

I have an Asus N56VZ with Windows 8 pre-installed.

Comment: I'm afraid that's only possible with a BIOS modification/downgrade, and I don't know if that's technically possible. Or you would have to ask ASUS if they could reimplement the legacy boot screen and hope they actually do it...

Comment: You can usually disable those splashscreens by accessing the CMOS. Once you power on your machine, press DEL to enter the setup and look through the entries for a setting that might turn it off.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried [this](http://www.ehow.com/how_7468696_delete-asus-boot-screen.html)?

1. Click "Start" and select "Shut down." Allow your computer to shut down completely and wait approximately 30 seconds.
2. Restart the computer and rapidly press the "Del" or "Delete" key on your keyboard. Continue pressing the key until you enter into the BIOS setup screen.
3. Navigate to the "Boot" menu and press "Enter." Use the directional arrows on the keyboard to navigate through the BIOS setup screen.
4. Scroll down and select "Boot Settings Configuration." Press "Enter." You will enter into the "Boot Settings Configuration" screen, where you can change options about how your system boots.
5. Scroll down and select "Full Screen Logo."
6. Press "-" or "+" on your keyboard to change the value to "Disabled."
7. Press "F10" to save your changes to the BIOS setup and restart your computer.

Comment: My BIOS does not have a "Boot Settings Configuration" entry. I did not find a comparable entry either.

Comment: Perhaps [Bios 217](http://support.asus.com/download.aspx?SLanguage=en&m=N56VZ&os=30) added an option. Else disabling fast boot and/or pressing escape while the logo shows might switch to boot text.